# Are there any prerequisites for powershell to be able to control IE navigation?

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, dom, automation

I am having a hard time with capturing output of a search in application browser.

The requirement:
1. Login to application URL.
2.Search
3.Capture result

I have a code and it works fine on one server but behaves weird on other machines. The powershell version and IE(11) are same on all of them. ON the good server, all works well. On the bad servers, powershell cannot get the element and class names for only point 3. It captures empty string each time. Even $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("body") returns empty on the bad servers.

I am new to powershell and not sure if I have missed out anything. Can anyone please suggest thoughts here?

Below is the code:

```
$username = "user1" 
$password = "pwd1" 
$url="application URL"
$search="tamanna"
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application' 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate($url)
while($ie.ReadyState -ne "4") 
{
start-sleep -Seconds 5;
}
($ie.document.getElementById("login-form-username") |select -first 1).value = $username;
($ie.document.getElementById("login-form-login-password") |select -first 1).value = $password;
$ie.document.getElementById("login-form-login").click()
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; }
$ie.navigate("Search URL within application")
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne "4") { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; }
$text=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | Where-Object{$_.className -eq 'class1_unique'} |select -first 1
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne "4") { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; }
$searchResult=$text.innerText
$searchResult
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your code to check whether there is some issue in it or not. Based on my testing results, your code is working fine on my side.

After some research, I found that the issue can be related to **Internet Explorer security settings**.

I noticed that I get the same behavior when the **Protected mode** is **enabled** for the **Internet zone**.

[image]

For testing purposes, you can try to **disable** the **Protected mode** for the **Internet** and **Local intranet** zone to see whether it helps to solves your issue. As an alternative, you can try to run the script as an **Administrator**.

To disable the protected mode, you can refer to the steps below.

1. Launch the **Internet Explorer** browser.
2. Click on **Tools** (ALT + X).
3. Click on **Internet options**.
4. Click on the **Security** tab.
5. **Unchecked** the **Enable protected mode** option for **Internet** and **Local intranet** zone.
6. **Restart** the Internet Explorer browser.

After that try to run your PowerShell script to see the result.

Let us know about your testing results, Whether it fixed this issue or not.

Comment: I followed your steps but it did not seem to fix the problem. Any other suggestions? Also, it is surpising that on the login  page, I can get $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("body"). However, after login, $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("body") gives me null value. I have checked ready state and it is 4. I am clueless on how to get this fixed,

Comment: Can you please inform us whether it is an intranet site or you access the site from the internet? For which zone you disabled the protected mode? Both URLs are part of the same domain? Did you try to run the script as an administrator?

Comment: It is an intranet site. That being said, please note that the code works fine on one server. Protected mode setting was same on both the servers(enabled for both local intranet and internet). I still did disable and try again on the bad server, the code did not work still. Yes, I have run the script as administrator as well :(

Comment: As I informed you, The issue is not related to the code. I think it is related to the settings or configuration. If you are running the script directly then try to open the script file using Windows Powershell ISE app and run the script to see whether it shows any error message.

Comment: I have been testing all this while using ISE app only, with debug and breakpoints enabled. Nothing helped me fix this. I do understand that this is with not able to get the $ie.Document.* after searching in my application URL but do not know how to get it working. About the settings, I wonder how to figure that out, everything looks alike at this point :(

Comment: Try to right click on the script file and click on Run with Powershell option. see whether it works or not. If issue persists then you can try to lower down the security settings (Just for testing purposes) in internet options, to see whether it makes any difference. If then also the issue persist then I suggest you to contact the IT department of your company. They may help to find you the cause for the issue.